# Using image data to create a 3D Histogram

Tags: plotting, image-processing, histograms

I have a black and white .tiff file of a beam spot:

[image: Beam profile]

I am trying to characterize the source in a Monte Carlo program, to do this I want to convert the image into a 3D Histogram with controllable bin size.

Haven't been able to figure out how to convert the image data to match Histogram3D[] input parameters, closest I've gotten so far are 3D plots  using:

`ListPlot3D[Reverse@ImageData@RemoveAlphaChannel@ColorConvert[beam1, "Grayscale"], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "intensity"}, PlotRange -> All]`

Any pointers on how to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Method 1: `Histogram3D`

Import and clean the image:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGWn6.jpg"];
i = RemoveAlphaChannel@ColorConvert[i, "Grayscale"]
```

`Histogram3D` looks at the number of points in the bins, but that is uniform for an image as indexes of pixels are uniform. So I guess besides that you want data weighted by pixel values:

```
dataW=
WeightedData[
    Flatten[Array[List,Reverse@ImageDimensions[i]],1],
    Flatten[ImageData[i],1]
]
```

Now you can bin in a custom way:

```
Histogram3D[dataW, {50, 60}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

With a little bit of style you can get it looking quite any way you want:

```
Histogram3D[dataW,{30,35},
    ChartElementFunction->
    ChartElementDataFunction["ProfileCube","Profile"->2.,"TaperRatio"->0.6],
    ColorFunction->"Rainbow",ChartStyle->Opacity[.5],PlotTheme->"Marketing"]
```

[image]

### Method 2: `ListPlot3D`

You could achieve a similar result differently, in a bit hack-ish way. Define data as:

```
data = ImageData[ImageResize[i, {30, 30}]];
```

so `ImageResize` spec 30x30 gives effective number of bins in X and Y directions. **Resizing an image is effectively binning** (in your specific case).

```
ListPlot3D[data,PlotRange->{{5,25},{10,25},All},InterpolationOrder->0,
ColorFunction->"Rainbow",Filling->Bottom,Mesh->None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add another data processing method

```
im1=RemoveAlphaChannel[
        ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGWn6.jpg"], 
         "Grayscale"]];
    data = ImageData[im1];
    dim = Dimensions[data];
    A = Flatten[
       Table[{i, j}, {i, dim[[2]]}, {j, dim[[1]]}, {k, 
         PixelValue[im1, {i, j}, "Byte"]}], 2];

Histogram3D[A, {{.5}, {2}}, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: fig1]